# How could I compact this jQuery script?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script for automatic scroll verically to different divs. The code is a bit messy tho, and I would like som helt with compact it since I'm new to jQuery.

My thoughts is that i somehow is possible to check what button is pressed and change what div to scroll to depending on that. Other than the button class and div class the code is the same.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Song 1 -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".song1_btn").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.song1').offset().left }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>

<!-- Song 2 -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".song2_btn").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.song2').offset().left }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>

<!-- Song 3 -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".song3_btn").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.song3').offset().left }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>

<!-- Song 4 -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".song4_btn").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.song4').offset().left }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>

<!-- Song 5 -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".song5_btn").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.song5').offset().left }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>

<!-- Song 6 -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".song6_btn").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.song6').offset().left }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That class is more suited as an ID. Classes usually describe a group of elements (eg. `.song`)

Comment: You have identical code where only a number changes. What do *you* think the refactor is?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't done any fine tuning into my html/css yet, but I would like to know how to compact the jQuery.

Comment: Dave - I know what the refactor is and tried to pass it in the question, but I don't know how to make it into one piece of jQuery script since I'm new to it. If you know how to do it, please show an example how I could do.

Comment: @Alexander: post your HTML markup if you want to get relevant answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery attribute selectors:

```
$('[class$="_btn"]').click(function() { //class name ends with "_btn"
    var firstPartOfClass = this.className.split('_')[0]; //"song4";
    var number = firstPartOfClass[firstPartOfClass.length - 1]; //"4"

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.song' + number).offset().left }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**: You can define your document.ready once and put all the script you want to use when the DOM is ready there.

**Second**: Since the click functionality in your jquery are basicly the same, you should try to create 1 function that you can use for all clickevents.

You could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="song_btn" data-animate="song_1">song 1</a>
<a href="#" class="song_btn" data-animate="song_2">song 2</a>
<a href="#" class="song_btn" data-animate="song_3">song 3</a>

<div class="song_1">
    song 1
</div>

<div class="song_2">
    song 2
</div>

<div class="song_3">
    song 3
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".song_btn").click(function(){
    var element = $(this).attr("data-animate");      
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: $('.' + element).offset().left }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>
```

This is a solution, but as they say there are many roads that lead to Rome...